# Set up SSL on email with Dovecot and Postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, ubuntu-16.04, apache2

On my server I installed Postfix and Dovecot and Apache2 on Ubuntu.

I bought a SSL certificate and used that to secure the website. This works fine.

Now I want to configure Postfix and Dovecot with the same certificate so that I can use my mail server with SSL too. But when I set it up on my gmail app on the phone, I get this:

```
Certificate not trusted
Subject: kanzan.se
Issuer: AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
Valid from: Jul 3, 2018
Expires on: Jul 4, 2019
Current date: Jul 6, 2018
PEM encoded chain: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFzTCCBLWgAwIBAgIMdmzZXlCIkPQV/MbvMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMEwxCzAJBgN...
```

This is my configurations:

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/kanzan_cert_comb.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/kanzan_ssl.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated
#reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf:

```
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/kanzan_cert_comb.crt
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/kanzan_ssl.key
```

/etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes

smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
```

First of all, can I use the same certificate for mail and the website? (same domain). I added a MX record to my DNS which points to this domain, kanzan.se.

Are my configs right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the *certificate chain* sent with the certificate. You can use the same certificate with Apache2, Postfix and Dovecot. However, the configuration for intermediate certificates is different: Apache has a separate [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) directive, while Postfix and Dovecot requires intermediate certificates to be in the same file (`smtpd_tls_cert_file` / `ssl_cert`).

Testing your current configuration with `openssl s_client -debug -connect`, both `kanzan.se:465` for SMTPS and `kanzan.se:443` for HTTPS shows only one certificate.

```
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=kanzan.se
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
```

This should show the intermediate certificates too, the full chain to the root CA being:

```
Certificate chain
  0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=kanzan.se
    i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
  1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=AlphaSSL CA - SHA256 - G2
    i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
  2 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
    i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
```

To set this up for Postfix and Dovecot (and Apache):

1. You can get the intermediate certificate from GlobalSign [AlphaSSL Intermediate Certificates](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1223298-alphassl-intermediate-certificates). You need the one with serial `040000000001444ef03631`.

   ```
   /etc/ssl/certs# wget https://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsalphasha2g2r1.crt
   ```

   The GlobalSign Root CA should be in `GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem`. You can check the serial:

   ```
   /etc/ssl/certs$ openssl x509 -in GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem -serial -noout
   serial=040000000001154B5AC394
   ```
2. All the certificates needs to be in ASCII armored PEM format, while the downloaded `gsalphasha2g2r1.crt` is currently in DER encoded binary format. You need to convert it using:

   ```
   openssl x509 -inform DER -in gsalphasha2g2r1.crt -out gsalphasha2g2r1.pem
   ```
3. Combine the certificates as explained in [Postfix TLS readme](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html). The order is same for [Dovecot](https://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration).

   ```
   cat kanzan_cert_comb.crt gsalphasha2g2r1.pem GlobalSign_Root_CA.pem > postfix.crt
   ```
4. Use these certificates:

   - Postfix: `smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/postfix.crt`
   - Docevot: `ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/postfix.crt`
   - Apache, add: `SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gsalphasha2g2r1.crt`

Comment: Thank you very much!! I made exactly these changes, but same thing. I tried openssl and the chain is still just one?? (The last cahnge SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gsalphasha2g2r1.crt made the page go down, I used my crt file I created when doing the request for the cert instead)

Comment: That's strange. And you have restarted all these services after modification? Does `cat postfix.crt` show all the three `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` blocks?

Comment: It looks like this: see UPDATE.. (The middle one is encoded differently)

Comment: I think I made a little mistake here: the intermediate certificate is now in binary format, while it should bee ASCII armored. I'd try to fix this to my answer and let you try again.

Comment: It work!! Thank you again very much! I just copied it instead

Comment: That'd work, too. Now my answer is complete.